# SQL audit to capture which method called a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, methods, capture, audit

We have a audit log table which captures the following data:

1. old value
2. new value
3. table name
4. field name
5. changed by
6. changed on

The audit log is implemented via a SQL trigger.

In our application one stored procedure is called by multiple .NET functions. We want to add a new field in the log which will store the name of the .NET function which called the SP, but we're not sure how this can be passed from .NET to a SQL trigger. Does anyone know to a way to do this?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Triggers have no idea why they've been called, or from where or anything. The only thing you know is the modified data, before and after the change.